# Insert multiple data into database using java for loop

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I'm working on a library management project. For every book that's having more than one copy I need to enter same details into the database but with different book number.

```
public class bookentry {
      public boolean addbook(int bid,String bname, String authname, Double bprice, int edition, String pub, String catname, int bcpy) {
        boolean st = false;
        try {
            DBconnection dbconnection = new DBconnection();
            java.sql.Connection com = dbconnection.getconnection();
            for(int i=0;bid>=1;i++){
            PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) com.prepareStatement("insert into book_master(bname, authname, bprice, edition, pub, catname, bcpy)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            stmt.setString(1, bname);
            stmt.setString(2, authname);
            stmt.setDouble(3, bprice);
            stmt.setInt(4, edition);
            stmt.setString(5, pub);
            stmt.setString(6, catname);
            stmt.setInt(7, bcpy);
            int count = stmt.executeUpdate();
            }
```

Comment: Your question is kind of matching your name. Just kidding. You need to show your partial progress here likely with what you have coded so far in order for us to help you move where you are stuck.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi could you check now

Comment: When is the connection commited and closed or is the connection in auto-commit mode?  Please consider using  at least 'try with resources'.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: @vizsatiz Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: code.bookentry.addbook

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi                                                                                if (count > 0) {
                st = true;
            } else {
                st = false;
              
            }
            stmt.close();
            com.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(bookentry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return st;
    }
}

Comment: @notorious: With that error message "Uncompilable source code" it seems your code isn't even compiling properly. Plus there are other issues I see too. Your for loops middle condition seems wrong. for(int i=0;bid>=1;i++) how does this for loop terminate? Also you need to close the PreparedStatement at the end of for loop else it leads to resource leakage

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi im really stuck could you help?

Comment: @notorious: please post more code that I can compile and run at my end.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi                                                                              code https://pastebin.com/f02N7FKX                                                                             form https://pastebin.com/8Dyy66Lx

Comment: ok I've seen your code. You need to make little changes in your addBook method. change forloop from this for(int i=0;bid>=1;i++) to for(int i=0;i<bid;i++) Here I am assuming bid is the number of entries you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesn't seem right so you may use replace your whole for loop with this for loop code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < bid; i++) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) com
            .prepareStatement("insert into book_master(bname, authname, bprice, edition, pub, catname, bcpy)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");) {
        stmt.setString(1, bname + i);
        stmt.setString(2, authname);
        stmt.setDouble(3, bprice);
        stmt.setInt(4, edition);
        stmt.setString(5, pub);
        stmt.setString(6, catname);
        stmt.setInt(7, bcpy);
        int count = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Try and let me know what further problems you face.